# 3D printing filament that can absorb photosensitive liquid

Tags: filament, filament-choice

I'm a student artist trying to use 3D printing in my practice a bit. I'm working with liquid light, which is essentially a photosensitive liquid that you can apply to surfaces and later develop in the darkroom. I'm hoping to do this on 3D models that I print and was looking for advice on a good filament to print with that would absorb the liquid light. The manufacturer of the liquid recommends using a semi-gloss or glossy clear polyurethane to treat nonabsorbent surfaces, but I was hoping to avoid this. Anything would be appreciated and helpful!

Comment: If PU works to treat existing surfaces, TPU - available in a lot of different hardnesses - sounds like a good thing to try.

Comment: Have you thought about using a porous design printed on a resin printer? of course the pores would be relatively big but surface tension would likely keep the part soaked.

Comment: @FarO If it's for purely artistic purposes and original surface quality doesn't matter, one could also try reducing the flow for the external perimeters so that the outside layer before ill-extruded and porous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PrusaSlicer](https://help.prusa3d.com/article/fuzzy-skin_246186) (free, multi-platform) supports a feature known as fuzzy skin. Text below from linked page. Additionally, Cura slicer and Super Slicer also support this feature.

> The Fuzzy skin feature lets you create a rough fiber-like texture on
> the sides of your models. If enabled, the perimeter will be resampled
> with a random step size and each new sample point will be shifted
> inside or outside of the perimeter by a random length limited by the
> Fuzzy skin thickness. This simple algorithm produces surprisingly nice
> results suitable for tool handles or just to give the print surface a
> new interesting look or to hide print imprecisions. You can also use
> modifiers to apply fuzzy skin only to a portion of your model.

This would result in a roughened surface, if the right parameters were used, allowing surface tension to secure itself while the "outward" or fuzzy portion might prevent shearing or peeling.